# Rearranging LGBMClassifier predict_proba outputs columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am training an `LGBMClassifier` for the purpose of using its `predict_proba` method.  The target has 3 classes: **a, b, and c**.  I want to ensure that the model `predict_proba` outputs the probabilities of the columns in order **b, a, c**.
*Is there a way to ensure that the output of* `LGBMClassifier` `predict_proba` *has the above ordering?*

```
import pandas as pd
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
import numpy as np

#data
features = ['feat_1']
TARGET = 'target'
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'feat_1':np.random.uniform(size=100),
    'target':np.random.choice(a=['b','c','a'], size=100)
})

#training
model = LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(df[features], df[TARGET])
print(model.classes_)
```

> ['a','b','c']

#### Things I Have Tried

1. Just rearrange the `.classes_` attribute.
   `model.classes_ = ['b','a','c']`

> AttributeError: can't set attribute 'classes_'

2. Manually rearrange the columns based on the `.classes_` attribute.

```
desired_order = ['b','a','c']
correct_idx = [list(model._classes).index(val) for val in desired_order]
model.predict_proba(test[features])[:, correct_idx]
```

#2 works, but I would just as soon not have to permute the column order every `predict_proba` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, the labels come in order ["a", "b", "c"] because the SkLearn framework sorts them lexicographically (ie. using [`numpy.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)). This behaviour cannot be disabled easily.

You may work around this by re-mapping labels from strings to integers:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
le.classes_ = np.asarray(["b", "a", "c"])

df[TARGET] = le.transform(df[TARGET])
```

The `LGBMClassifier` will return a three-element array from its `predict_proba` method, where the elements correspond to "b", "a" and "c" labels, respectively.

Sure, the downside is that the `predict` method will be returning integer class labels also.